# pandas replace multiple values (that you do not know) on one column

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

What is the best way to change several values in a column ('Status') that differ from the only two values that you want to analyse?
As an example, my df is:

```
Id  Status  Email   Product Age
1   ok          g@      A       20
5   not ok      l@      J       45
1   A           a@      A       27
2   B           h@      B       25 
2   ok          t@      B       33
3   C           b@      E       23
4   not ok      c@      D       30
```

In the end, I want to have:

```
Id  Status  Email   Product Age
1   ok          g@      A       20
5   not ok      l@      J       45
1   other       a@      A       27
2   other       h@      B       25 
2   ok          t@      B       33
3   other       b@      E       23
4   not ok      c@      D       30
```

The greatest difficulty is that my df is very huge, so I do not know all the others values different than 'ok' and 'not ok' (the values that I want to analise).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bad choice in answers, `apply` is loads slower than Wen's solution with `np.where`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.where` + `isin`

```
df.Status=np.where(df.Status.isin(['ok','not ok']),df.Status,'Others')
df
Out[384]: 
   Id  Status Email Product  Age
0   1      ok    g@       A   20
1   5  not ok    l@       J   45
2   1  Others    a@       A   27
3   2  Others    h@       B   25
4   2      ok    t@       B   33
5   3  Others    b@       E   23
6   4  not ok    c@       D   30
```

Answer (score 0):

use an apply

```
df['Status'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'other' if x['Status'] not in ['ok', 'not ok'] else x['Status'], axis=1)
```